# Symfony 2, one form (but many times) on one page

Tags: php, forms, symfony

The idea of comments for my page, and I want to make "comment a comment". So i need to show one form but many times for example:

```
foreach ($entities as $entity)
  echo $view['form']->widget($form['text']);
```

And it works only for the first iteration. What I have to do?
addition..

p.s. mb we can render already rendered form?

Comment: I'm curious, did you try the bundle I found? How is it? I'm thinking about incorporating it into my latest project.

Comment: I've tried to use it in my test project & it's rather nice. But I want to find my own way to make such forms) I mean forms for commenting comments... I don't think it's smth unbelievable hard. But now I have exams so mb a lil bit later we'll do smth with it :)

Comment: in conclusion, I made in a such way: I made hidden layer, with a necessary form; and with the help of `js` (jquerys `.append()`) I show & hide this block in all necessary places. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are doing comments on other comments, you should need to pass a hidden field with the ID of what you are commenting on. That would require different forms for each.

Alternatively, as creating a different form object for every comment would be rather annoying, you can output the form manually and insert the hidden field for the comment.

There is also a threaded comments bundle available for Symfony. I haven't tested it yet (its on my todo list for my app) but it might take care of all your problems: http://knpbundles.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the embedded forms? You will iterate on the one form and in one field witch contain the child forms related to the entity.

Comment: but if i have an unknown amount of places where i need to insert a form? or we can deal with it?

Answer (score 1):

I think, what you are looking for is the [collection type](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html).

Comment: Hm.. mbmb. but I make a recursive comments print. Hm, and i simply wanted to make a sort of "own comment box send" but they are all similar, so it would be for each comment smth like this(no matter root, node or leaf): `~print comment~ && ~print box to send comment(I want to mark - for each its own!)~`